# how to pick up weak bluetooth signal

Tags: sensor, bluetooth

my daughter is diabetic, she wears a glucose sensor that transmits the values on bluetooth but the receiver has to be no more than 2 inches away. is there a device sensitive enough to pick up the weak signal from lets say, 20 inches? an antenna? during her sleep monitoring becomes tough for everybody. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is BT? It's too close to be it. More like NFC.

Comment: What do the medical people say?

Comment: While the subject matter is sympathetic, this can't be dealt with in an engineering manner without engineering details of the device.   A model number or better FCC ID would be a starting point, but it may not be sufficient for the question to be considered on-topic here.  *Most end-user questions about consumer products are not on topic here*.

Comment: I am almost 100% sure you don't actually mean "bluetooth". It's going to be difficult to help when we don't know all the details.

Comment: It sounds like something jarred or moisture shifted the sender or tuner frequency, because BT ought to work much much further. (several to many meters) Check battery then check supplier for defective RMA.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to post a model number.

Comment: You're right, is NFC. The available info on the packages do not give any details. In Abbot's website for freestyle libre sensor, there is no further info other than mentioning the NFC capabilities. Thanks for your feedback guys. I appreciate the minutes you took to respond.

Answer (score 1):

My daughter uses an insulin pump as well, a MiniMed 640G from Medtronics.

It does not use Bluetooth but IEEE 802.15.4 see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4  which uses the same frequencies but is **not** BlueTooth.

It is possible that your pump does use Bluetooth though.

Any device that is adhering to the Bluetooth standard should have a range of several meters. So the fact that in your case the range is less means it might not be Bluetooth at all.

Anyway just picking up the signal is not an issue, that can almost always be done if you have the right equipment and the signal is not disturbed too much.

What is an issue is that relying just on "not being able to pickup the signal" is not a good idea if you want security (to stop others from messing with the pump).

So the security is implemented on a different level, at the datastream which is **encrypted**. This is the case for Bluetooth and it can be expected that similar protocols use encryption as well.

This should prevent (or at least make it very difficult) to make a connection with the insulin pump.

So picking up the signal is not the issue. The issue is making a useful data connection (a link) with the device. It is similar to hearing a conversation in a language you do not understand, the fact that you can hear it does not mean you can participate in it or extract information from it.